# Creating dictionaries with pre-defined keys C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I'm looking for a way to define a dictionary for reuse. ie. I can create the dictionary object without having to populate it with the values I want.

Here is what I have currently (note code not tested, just example)

```
public Dictionary<string, string> NewEntryDictionary()
{
    Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    // populate key value pair
    foreach(string name in Enum.GetNames(typeof(Suits))
    {
        dic.Add(name, "");
    }

    return dic;
}
```

The end result should be a new dictionary object with a predefined set of keys.
But I want to avoid doing it this way.

Comment: *Why* do you want to avoid doing it this way? If you don't tell us what you don't like about the current option, we can't help you do it differently.

Comment: I think it creates more code than needed. I also think it involves all these iterations which imo is inefficient.

Comment: How would you expect to populate a dictionary with N items without N iterations?

Comment: I'm thinking there might be a way to do this much like you define enumerations.

Comment: No, there isn't - it would be pretty peculiar if there were, IMO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not really clear whether you're concerned about the amount of code you've written, or the efficiency of it. From an efficiency perspective, it's fine - it's O(N), but that's hard to avoid if you're populating a dictionary with N entries.

You can definitely make the source code shorter though, using LINQ:

```
public Dictionary<string, string> NewEntryDictionary()
{
    return Enum.GetNames(typeof(Suits)).ToDictionary(name => name, name => "");
}
```

That won't be any more efficient, of course... it's just shorter code.

Answer (score 0):

If you do ONLY want to save values according to your enum, use 
`Dictionary<Suits,String>` instead of `Dictionary<String,String>`

Everything else, Jon already said. Use LinQ for a bit more "fancy" look. But that does not do better performance