# Define Dictionary with prepoluated keys c#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a class `Properties` and in that I have defined a dictionary like this :

```
 public class Properties
    {
        public IDictionary<string, string> ExtendedProperties
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
```

In the dictionary, there will be 3 keys always present say `Name`,`Number` and `Age` with the option of adding more `KeyValuePairs` during runtime.

I want to have the 3 keys described above to be present in the dictionary by default while initializing it in my code so that I can use it directly like this:

```
Properties objProps = new Properties();
objProps.ExtendedProperties["Name"] = "SomeName";
```

I know I can achieve this in my code by adding the KeyValuePair to the dictionary but I was hoping to have it setup directly in the class using `get-set` to include the 3 keys. I could not find any solution that does that in the class itself. I looked into this [Creating dictionaries with predefined keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26160503/creating-dictionaries-with-pre-defined-keys-c-sharp) but did not find it satisfactory.

how can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you aware of [Constructors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ace5hbzh.aspx)?  You may want/need to do some OOP reading

Comment: @JamesThorpe yes you are right. I didn't even think of constructors. My bad.

Comment: you can assign your default dictionary right after         `{
            get;
            set;
        } = new Dictionary.....`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since C# 6 you can do something like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Properties
{
    public IDictionary<string, string> ExtendedProperties { get; set; }

    public Properties(string name, string number, string age) 
    {
        this.ExtendedProperties = new Dictionary<string, string>() 
        { 
            ["Name"] = name,
            ["Number"] = number,
            ["Age"] = age
        };
    }
}
```

As you can see you need to define it in the constructor.

There is also some cool function you might want to use:

```
public int this[int param]
{
    get { return array[param]; }
    set { array[param] = value; }
}
```

[Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/dk1507sz.aspx)

If you add something like this, you can do `new Properties()["Name"]`

Example with your code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Properties
{
    private IDictionary<string, string> extendedProperties;

    public string this[string key] 
    {
        get { return extendedProperties[key]; }
        set { extendedProperties[key] = value; }        
    }

    public Properties() 
    {
        this.extendedProperties = new Dictionary<string, string>() 
        { 
            ["Name"] = "something",
            ["Number"] = "something",
            ["Age"] = "something"
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: The extension method is a very nice touch!

Answer (score 1):

How about adding the 3 entries in the constructor?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace My.Namespace
{
    public class Properties
    {
        public IDictionary<string, string> ExtendedProperties { get; set; }

        public Properties()
        {
            ExtendedProperties = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                ["Name"] = String.Empty,
                ["Number"] = String.Empty,
                ["Age"] = String.Empty
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that will throw a `KeyNotFoundException` ... how's about creating an instance first? ** yeaaaah.. messed up :p my bad.. ** `NullReferenceException`

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
public class Properties
    {
        public IDictionary<string, string> ExtendedProperties
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

      public Properties()
      {
         this.ExtendedProperties = new Dictionary<string, string>()
         {
            { "Name", String.Empty },
            { "Number", String.Empty },
            { "Age", String.Empty },
         };

      }
    }
```

You might want to have a look at some documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531208.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can do this.

```
 public class Properties
 {
     public IDictionary<string, string> ExtendedProperties
     {
         get;
         set;
     }

     public Properties(string [] fields)
     {
         ExtendedProperties = new Dictionary<string, string> ();
         foreach(var s in fields)
         {
             ExtendedProperties.Add(s,string.Empty);
         }
     }
 }
```

**Usage :**

```
Properties p = new Properties(new [] {"Name","Number", "Age"});
```

Working fiddler [code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Xw4eC2)

Answer (score 1):

I would go with implementing `IDictionary<string, string>` because it is more safe and easier to extend with other keys: (long class to follow)

```
class Properties : IDictionary<string, string>
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> _staticProps;
    private Dictionary<string, string> _otherProps;

    public Properties()
    {
        _staticProps = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"Name", "" },
            {"Number", "" },
            {"Age", "" }
        };
        _otherProps = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }

    public ICollection<string> Keys
    {
        get
        {
            return (ICollection<String>)_otherProps.Keys.Concat(_staticProps.Keys);
        }
    }

    public ICollection<string> Values
    {
        get
        {
            return (ICollection<String>)_otherProps.Values.Concat(_staticProps.Values);
        }
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return _otherProps.Count + _staticProps.Count;
        }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public string this[string key]
    {
        get
        {
            if (_otherProps.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                return _otherProps[key];
            }
            if(_staticProps.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                return _staticProps[key];
            }
            throw new KeyNotFoundException(key);
        }

        set
        {
            if (_otherProps.ContainsKey(key) || _staticProps.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("key exists: " + key);
            }
            _otherProps[key] = value;
        }
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(string key)
    {
        return _otherProps.ContainsKey(key) || _staticProps.ContainsKey(key);
    }

    public void Add(string key, string value)
    {
        _otherProps.Add(key, value);
    }

    public bool Remove(string key)
    {
        if (_staticProps.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("key is static, cannot be removed: " + key);
        }
        return _otherProps.Remove(key);
    }

    public bool TryGetValue(string key, out string value)
    {
        return _otherProps.TryGetValue(key, out value) || _staticProps.TryGetValue(key, out value);
    }

    public void Add(KeyValuePair<string, string> item)
    {
        if (_staticProps.ContainsKey(item.Key))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("key exist an is static: " + item.Key);
        }
        _otherProps.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _otherProps.Clear();
        foreach (var key in _staticProps.Keys)
        {
            _staticProps[key] = string.Empty;
        }
    }

    public bool Contains(KeyValuePair<string, string> item)
    {
        return _otherProps.Contains(item) || _staticProps.Contains(item);
    }

    public void CopyTo(KeyValuePair<string, string>[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {           
        // define yourself how you want to handle arrayIndex between the two dictionaries
    }

    public bool Remove(KeyValuePair<string, string> item)
    {
        if (_staticProps.ContainsKey(item.Key))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("key is static, cannot be removed: " + item.Key);
        }
        return _otherProps.Remove(item.Key);
    }

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, string>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _otherProps.Concat(_staticProps).GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _otherProps.Concat(_staticProps).GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would encapsulate this logic in property itself:

```
public class Properties
{
    private IDictionary<string, string> _extendedProperties;
    public IDictionary<string, string> ExtendedProperties
    {
        get
        {
            return
                _extendedProperties == null ?
                    new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "Name", "" }, { "Number", "" }, { "Age", "" } } :
                    _extendedProperties;
        }
        set 
        { 
            _extendedProperties = value; 
            //here you can also check if value misses those key to add them to _extendedProperties
        }
    }
}
```